# How to use username based url in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, url-rewriting

I am trying to create user based JSP web application. And in this app, I want to add profile feature like social networking website and it will look like site/Username and site/UserProfile etc.

Believe me, I don't want make any other unwanted social networking website. But in my site I want to add feature like site/Username/about to show about page of that particular person "Username" and other features like site/Username/contact, site/Username/skills etc. If person is logged in then I want to use site/Username/settings, site/Username/account, site/Username/edit etc. So can anyone tell me how can I create this webapp with JAVA/JSP? Using servlet, I can do site/settings, site/accounts, site/edit etc but I don't want to do this. I want to do as I described (with username feature). Can anyone suggest me what should I do and if there is any framework that can help me with please let me know. Right now, I am using only jsp/java with eclipse so do I need to change IDE?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at Tuckey URL Rewrite filter

Comment: Ya, I found it. But any other tip for my question?

Answer (score 1):

There are various Web Frameworks that enable you to develop RESTFul Web Applications (e.g. Struts, JSF, Spring MVC etc). I personally prefer Spring MVC, you can read more about it [here](http://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use any API for any stuff other than servlet to get it done.
All you need is to use `request.getPathInfo()` .

you will have to create a controller servlet or a filter for example `site` as you have specified in your question. This `site` servlet will act as a controller, you will use `site/Anurag/contact` , where `Anurag` is the name of a user, in this case it is me.
`request.getPathInfo()` will return `/Anurag/contact`.

you can deal it like this

```
String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
String[] pathParams = {};
if(validations for pathInfo){
 pathInfo  = pathInfo.substring(pathInfo.indexOf("/")+1);    
 pathParams  =  pathInfo.split("/");
}
```

pathParams[0] will have username

pathParams[1] will have the name of operation the user wants to perform

```
if(pathParams[1].equalsIgnoreCase("contact")){
    then redirect to View for contact
}
```

OR

```
if(pathParams[1].equalsIgnoreCase("setting")){
    then redirect to View for setting
}
```

It can be implemented in this way. 
I think `stackoverflow` redirects to Questions in the same way.May be it uses APIs,I don't know, but it will clear the message that I want to convey.

When you hit the *Questions* button on the page, it displays this URL `http://stackoverflow.com/questions` .

You can directly write down the question number after this URL and it will take you to that question. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920116` . This is way it is passes the question number.

In the same way This Usename specific URL can be implemented. You will have to make `site` a controller.